# How do I get this wing to uv unwrap correctly

Tags: uv

Im completely new to blender.  I'm trying to recreate this drawing of a butterfly my daughter did so I can bring it into Unity and surprise her with it.  I'm able to unwrap the bottom wing by adding a seam around it, and then down the side.  But when I try with the top wing things go crazy.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong and any help would be appreciated :)

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Comment: You want to give it a texture that is already existing?

Comment: in edit mode select only faces of the wing. face your viewport on the face vertically (Shift + Numpad 7), and then unwrap it in "Project from view" mode. It will give a nice flat projection even with no seams.

Comment: @mechanic thank you I will try that.  moonboots I don't have a texture just a crayon drawing I was going to try to recreate in photoshop for the skin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe join the eyes, in my opinion it's simpler to have only one object.

Your problem is that you have overlapping vertices, it messes up your unwrap, you need to select all in *Edit* mode and <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd> > *Merge By Distance*.

Make sure that your seams are well placed, i.e. all along the shapes as if it was a costume sewed (see screenshot). Then you can unwrap.

You can increase or decrease the size of some islands (UV map elements) in the *UV Editor*.

At the end you'll probably need to apply the *Mirror* modifier for Unity, by default I guess the mirrored left part will overlap the right part in the *UV Editor*.

[image]